# RODBC::odbcDriverConnect using Access driver fails without relative path to filename

Tags: r, rodbc

After much testing I found a confusing trait in the R package RODBC. With the function `RODBC::odbcDriverConnect`, I couldn't make a connection to an mdb file that was in R's working directory. A co-worker suggested I add `./` to the filename for a relative path. Doing that, the connection worked. To test this you'd need to create your own MS Access mdb file. I guess this is a trait of the MS drivers and not RODBC?

```
filename <- "test.mdb"
filename.relative <- paste0("./", filename)

driver.name <- "Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};"
driver.name <- paste0(driver.name, "DBQ=", filename)
#fails:
con <- RODBC::odbcDriverConnect(driver.name)
```

The error message I get is:

```
Warning messages:
1: In RODBC::odbcDriverConnect(driver.name) :
  [RODBC] ERROR: state HY000, code -1044, message [Microsoft]
[ODBC Microsoft Access Driver] Not a valid file name.
2: In RODBC::odbcDriverConnect(driver.name) : ODBC connection failed

#Second try:
driver.name <- "Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};"
driver.name <- paste0(driver.name, "DBQ=", filename.relative)

#works given it includes relative path:
con <- RODBC::odbcDriverConnect(driver.name)
RODBC::odbcCloseAll()
```

Comment: I wouldn't be so sure of that. When I dig into the `odbcDriverConnect` function, and follow it down to the call to `C_RODBCDriverConnect`, I find a reference to a dll in my home R path. Do you get an error message when you omit the relative path?

Comment: revised my post to include the error message.

Comment: I can reproduce this symptom with the Access ODBC driver, and it does not behave the same with the SQLite3 ODBC driver (that is, not including path with the SQLite3 driver still works as one might expect). From this it appears to be specific to MS Access.

Comment: perhaps I should revise the posting title to include "MS Access"?

Comment: How much of a problem is it? Unless I'm missing something, it's more of an annoyance than anything, having to prepend `./` to the beginning of a database file.